# The head of the snake is a couple points away from the body (c++ game)

Tags: c++, linux

Ive been working on this project for a while now and I cant find my problem in my project.
URL:https://github.com/blackwolf12333/Snake
The snake is a couple of points away from the body and doesnt seem to be moving. I had a segfault before, which I fixed, but I cant find the problem of this error! Ive tried almost anything, rewritng the code to reading it from beginning to end. Its coded in Linux!

main.c

```
#include "snake.h"
#include "ncurses.h"

void update();
void draw_snake();
void check_move(int c);

void cleanup();

int main() {
initscr();
noecho();
cbreak();

snake = create_snake_at(20, 10);
add_body_part(&snake.head);
//add_body_part(snake.head.next);

int key;
printw("Press any key to continue...");
while((key = getch()) != 'q') { // when 'q' is pressed the game will exit.
check_move(key);
update(); // updates game logic/graphics
refresh();
}
refresh();
endwin();
cleanup();
return 0;
}

void update() {
    //clear();
    move_snake();
    draw_snake();
}

void check_move(int c) {
    switch(c) {
    case 6517: // up arrow
move_up();
break;
case 6617:
move_down();
break;
case 6817:
move_left();
break;
case 6717:
move_right();
break;
default:
break;
    }
    draw_snake();
}

void print_body_part(body_part_t *part) {
    move(part->pos.y, part->pos.x);
if(part->head) {
addch('$'); 
} else {
addch('*');
}
}

void draw_snake() {
    body_part_t *next = &snake.head;
    int i = 0;
    while(next) {
        move(i, 0);
        printw("part is head: %d\tpart x: %d\tpart y: %d\n", next->head, next->pos.x, next->pos.y);
        print_body_part(next);
        next = next->next;
        i++;
    }
}

void cleanup() {
    body_part_t *next;
    for(next = &snake.head; next != NULL; next = next->next) {
        //free(next);
    }
}
```

move.c

```
#include "move.h"
#include "snake.h"

//TODO: add collision logic here!
void move_up() {
snake.head.pos.y++;
}

void move_down() {
snake.head.pos.y--;
}

void move_left() {
snake.head.pos.x--;
}

void move_right() {
snake.head.pos.x++;
}
```

move.h

```
#ifndef MOVE_H
#define MOVE_H

void move_up();
void move_down();
void move_left();
void move_right();

#endif
```

position.c

```
#include "position.h"

void initialize_position(position_t *pos, int x, int y) {
pos->x = x;
pos->y = y;
}
```

position.h

```
#ifndef POSITION_H
#define POSITION_H

typedef struct position {
int x;
int y;
} position_t;

void initialize_position(position_t *pos, int x, int y);

#endif
```

snake.c

```
#include "snake.h"

body_part_t create_body_part(int head, int x, int y);
position_t get_position_next_to(body_part_t *part);

void add_body_part(body_part_t *prev) {
body_part_t *part = malloc(sizeof(body_part_t));
part->head = prev->head & 0;
part->pos = get_position_next_to(prev);
part->dir = prev->dir;
part->next = NULL;
prev->next = part;
}

snake_t create_snake_at(int x, int y) {
snake_t *snake = malloc(sizeof(snake_t));
body_part_t head = create_body_part(1, x, y);
snake->head = head;
snake->health = MAX_HEALTH;
return *snake;
}

body_part_t create_body_part(int head, int x, int y) {
body_part_t *part = malloc(sizeof(body_part_t));
part->head = head;
initialize_position(&part->pos, x, y);
part->dir = LEFT;
part->next = NULL;
return *part;
}

position_t get_position_next_to(body_part_t *part) {
    position_t pos;
    switch(part->dir) {
    case UP:
        initialize_position(&pos, part->pos.x, part->pos.y++);
        break;
    case DOWN:
        initialize_position(&pos, part->pos.x, part->pos.y--);
        break;
    case LEFT:
        initialize_position(&pos, part->pos.x--, part->pos.y);
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        initialize_position(&pos, part->pos.x++, part->pos.y++);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return pos;
}

void move_snake() {
body_part_t *next;
for(next = &snake.head; next != NULL; next = next->next) {
switch(next->dir) {
case UP:
move_up();
break;
case DOWN:
move_down();
break;
case LEFT:
move_left();
break;
case RIGHT:
move_right();
break;
}
}
}
```

snake.h

```
#ifndef SNAKE_H
#define SNAKE_H

#include "stdlib.h"
#include "position.h"
#include "move.h"

#define MAX_HEALTH 20

typedef struct body_part body_part_t;

typedef enum DIR {
UP,
DOWN,
LEFT,
RIGHT
} direction;

typedef struct body_part {
int head;
position_t pos;
direction dir;
body_part_t *next;
} body_part_t;

typedef struct snake {
body_part_t head;
int health;
} snake_t;

/*
This is the main snake struct, if later multiple snakes will be implemented this should be replaced with something else
*/
snake_t snake;

snake_t create_snake_at(int x, int y);
void add_body_part(body_part_t *prev);
void move_snake();

#endif
```

Comment: Please post a `Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example` (http://sscce.org/) of your question. Don't expect someone to pull your github project and solve everything for you.

Comment: The whole code is no longer than 200 lines, I thought github would be easier to read, but ill add the code in the first post soon.

Comment: @JohnSmith, you're missing the "Short and Self Contained" part.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure which part of the code to post, because I don't know where my mistake is. Short(small) - 200 lines isn't that much... self contained, isn't it? copy, paste, compile, everything done. I'm not sure what do you mean by example? I explained the problem I am facing and seeking help for.. I tried everything, even rewriting the whole code..

Comment: @JohnSmith this isn't a forum for posting code for general debugging; if you narrow down the problem to a specific piece of code that you don't understand the behavior of and produce a SSCCE test case, someone will definitely be kind enough to help

Comment: I did read it and every part of the code I posted is related to my problem, I understand it's not a forum, but what am I supposed to do?

Comment: @JohnSmith narrow it down to a simpler case that demonstrates the problem; it's a necessary debugging skill, and you might even figure out the problem yourself while doing so

Comment: I swear I tried everything I could, from the beginning to the end, nothing solved my problem, nor I managed to find what it is, I thought of asking for help online, or simply abandon the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is probably partly in the get_next_position_to function, where you increment the position of the body part passed into the function.  I think this should probably only add.  The 'RIGHT' case also modifies both X and Y.

```
position_t get_position_next_to(body_part_t *part) {
    position_t pos;
    switch(part->dir) {
    case UP:
        initialize_position(&pos, part->pos.x, part->pos.y + 1);
        break;
    case DOWN:
        initialize_position(&pos, part->pos.x, part->pos.y - 1);
        break;
    case LEFT:
        initialize_position(&pos, part->pos.x - 1, part->pos.y);
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        initialize_position(&pos, part->pos.x + 1, part->pos.y);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Additionally, your move_snake function does not update the following body parts.  Since you are using a linked list, you could move the last element of the list to just after the head and copy the position etc from the head to the next element before moving the head.  You'd need to change your list to a bidirectional list for that.  You could code this far more efficiently with a circular buffer instead.

Your list cleanup function is wrong, since you free the next element before accessing it again.  You need to store a temporary and iterate and then free the temporary.  And you definitely shouldn't free &snake.head as you didn't malloc it.  It should be something like this:

```
void cleanup() {
    body_part_t* tmp;
    body_part_t *next = snake.head.next;
    while (next) {
        tmp = next;
        next = next->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally someone who decided to look up my code and help me. I appreciate your help very much, I'll try to fix my mistakes asap.